# What is the best way to switch urls in got?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, jsdom, node.js-got

I was doing some simple scraping using got and jsdom and I faced a challenge: what is the best thing to do in case we have multiple urls and we want to switch from one to another and check for a specific content because the content we are scraping is available only in one of them. for example we have:

```
const res = await got(url_1);
const {window : {document}} = new JSDOM(res.body);

let txt = document.querySelector(selector).textContent
```

now we're not sure that txt has any content so we move to the next url. I tried this:

```
if(!txt){
const res = await got(url_2);
const {window : {document}} = new JSDOM(res.body);
}

txt = document.querySelector(selector).textContent;
```

so at the end my code is sth like this:

```
const res = await got(url_1);
const {window : {document}} = new JSDOM(res.body);

let txt = document.querySelector(selector).textContent;

if(!txt){
const res = await got(url_2);
const {window : {document}} = new JSDOM(res.body);
}

obj.txt = document.querySelector(selector).textContent;

await Stock.findOneAndUpdate({symb: "symb"} , obj ,{upsert: true , useFindAndModify : false})
```

but it doesn't work properly.

Comment: What makes you ask? Does your code not work? Does it throw errors?

Comment: I edited my question. now anyone can tell me what's wrong? I think it has sth to do with sync and async concept

Comment: You can't globally `await`, so can you please read through the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask) and update your code to be an actual [mcve]? Try to write your post in terms of what you _actually_ do, not "something like". Also, never say "it doesn't work": your code does exactly what you've written it to do, and if it's not throwing errors, it clearly works. Instead, describe (a) what you're trying to achieve, (b) what code you wrote to do that, (c) what you're seeing it do instead, and (d) what you've already tried (so people don't recommend solutions you already tried).